# How do I customize mongo query comparison rule

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some data that are dates alike:

```
  2013-03-26 05:33:15
  2013-03-26 16:48:39
  ...
```

And I don't wanna compare them with my query using the default Date() way. Because I'm only interested in knowing if the daytime matches (hour:min +/- 10min).

E.g., if I query for `05:28:15`, it should returns the entry that contains "`2013-03-26 05:33:15`"

I have been trying to find some hints using the keyword "customize mongodb query" but it doesn't yield any result.

I'm wondering if this is at all possible or if there're some alternatives.

Comment: I modified the title a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the time you want to find and subtract/add your tolerance and search using a range:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

# Test Data
client.test.times.remove()
client.test.times.insert({ 'date': datetime(2013,03,26,05,33,15)})
client.test.times.insert({ 'date': datetime(2013,03,26,16,48,39)})


def get_approx_datetime(dt):
    start = dt-timedelta(minutes=10)
    end = dt+timedelta(minutes=10)
    return (start,end)


find_date = datetime(2013,03,26,05,28,15)
(start,end) = get_approx_datetime(find_date)


for time in client.test.times.find({ 'date': { '$gt': start, '$lt': end} }):
    print time
```

Outputs:

```
{u'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 26, 5, 33, 15), u'_id': ObjectId('517cb34f1d41c806aec7c4ad')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all matches for an hour and minute range with a `$where` clause. For your example, where we want to match 05:28 +/- 10 minutes:

```
client.collection.times.find({"$where": "this.Date.getHours() == 5 && this.Date.getMinutes() >= 18 && this.Date.getMinutes() <= 38"})
```